# Displaying Laravel Voyager Images in templates

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, voyager

Per their instructions, I'm attempting to pull out my images uploaded through admin with this:

```
{{ Voyager::image( $brand->logo ) }}
```

Instead of getting a url, it instead gives me an url with an appended JSON item:

```
http://job-tool.test/storage/[{"download_link":"brands\/April2018\/3Yrma1PZogiMiYOFmPGg.png","original_name":"logo_petiq.png"}]
```

PetIQ

Running just `{{ $brand->logo }}` gives me the array without the prepended url. What am I missing here?

I've also attempted to just use this: `{{ Voyager::image( $brand->logo->download_link ) }}` but I receive this error:

```
Trying to get property 'download_link' of non-object (View: /Users/johnbriggs/Code/Laravel/job-tool/resources/views/brands/show.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about trying;

`{{ Voyager::image( $brand->logo->download_link ) }}`

Having looked at the voyager package the Voyager::image function is

```
   public function image($file, $default = '')
    {
        if (!empty($file)) {
            return Storage::disk(config('voyager.storage.disk'))->url($file);
        }
        return $default;
    }
```

So could you try something like

```
<?php 
$file = (json_decode($brand->logo))[0]->download_link;
?>
{{ Voyager::image( $file ) }}
```

Although I appreciate this is a less than clean approach.

Comment: I thought that might work too... I've put that error above.

Comment: Can you `dd($brand->logo);` and place the response here?

Comment: It's funny. I absolutely love the tool, but I've never worked with something that looked so well-made, but was lacking so much documentation.

Comment: It returns this string when I do that:

`"[{"download_link":"brands\/April2018\/ffylOcWa38ZuzoP9koMc.png","original_name":"logo_betsyfarms.png"}]"`

Comment: I've noticed you work with Laravel quite a bit. Is there an admin panel solution you'd recommend looking into? I'm fairly new to the world of Laravel.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with another suggestion. Re admin panels - not overly. I tend to custom build mine depending on what is needed. I've heard some good things about voyager, but never really used it.

Comment: I just tried that and I actually get the same error as before the json_decode. I hear you with the custom admin. I was hoping this would cut down on time but for every hour it seems to save me, I end up spending 4 researching why it doesn't work. At this point I'm really only sticking with it for the user groups and permissions but I don't think that would be hard to find a package to help solve that

Comment: What happens if you use `{{ asset((json_decode($brand->logo))->download_lin) }}` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168957/discussion-between-brunam-and-simon-r).

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem one year later. The above answer by Simon R worked fine for me. Just echo the decoded json inside an image tag. Something like this:

```
    <img src="{{ Voyager::image( $file ) }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{{Voyager::image($article->thumbnail('medium','cover'))}}
```

And this is the validation of the cover field in Voyager :

```
{
    "resize": {
        "width": "728",
        "height": null
    },
    "quality": "80%",
    "upsize": true,
    "thumbnails": [
        {
            "name": "medium",
            "scale": "50%"
        },
        {
            "name": "small",
            "scale": "27%"
        }
    ],
    "validation": {
        "rule": "required"
    }
}
```